# Менять ячейки или вьюшки?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift

Здравствуйте.
Имею ячейку меню ресторана с фотографией блюда, ценой, именем и кнопкой добавления в корзину.
После нажатия по этой кнопке она должна исчезнуть и появится что-то вроде [ - 1шт + ]

Как правильно реализовать: после нажатия на кнопку "положить в корзину" - создать предварительно еще одну ячейку с нужным видом и после нажатия менять ее или же скрыть кнопку(button.hidden =true) и параллельно отобразить вьюшку с моими кнопками +-

Спасибо. Если правильный первый вариант, скажите пожалуйста какими методами пользоваться, чтобы по клику подменить одну ячейку на другую

Еще раз спасибо

**Обновление**

Тогда разрешите спросить, как внутри IBAction кнопки правильно найти мою вью с кнопками и лэйблом?

У вьюшки внутри которой расположеный две кнопки +- и лейбл назначил тег - 1

Сейчас реализовал так

```
@IBAction func buttonAddToCart(sender: AnyObject) {

  var button: UIButton = sender as UIButton // переданный объект sender преобразую в ОбъектКнопку    
  var viewMoreOrLess = button.superview.superview.viewWithTag(1) // нахожу вьюшку с кнопками +-    
  button.hidden = true // скрываю кнопку   
  viewMoreOrLess.hidden = false // делаю видимой вью с +-    
}
```

Работает но настораживает - superview.superview

**Обновление 2**

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` вызывается при клике по ячейке и это действие разворачивает полное описание блюда, поэтому оно не подходит.

Засунул все экшины и аутлеты в кастомный класс моей ячейки `UITableViewCell` и все стало на свои места, все работат

Спасибо [[@tragvar](/users/11201/tragvar)](/users/11201/tragvar) огромное.

Comment: да незачто ))
я был уверен, что у вас сразу был кастомный класс для ячеек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так можно же в ячейку добавить UIStepper + UIlabel спрятанные(или ваши кнопки +- и UIlabel). По нажатию на "положить в корзину" сделать (button.hidden = true), а спрятанные показать. Зачем вам еще одна ячейка?

**Обновление**

Извиняюсь, не заметил, что у вас swift.

Но там должен быть такой метод который вам сразу определяет в какой ячейке вы находитесь, а потом по индексу этой ячейки уже делаете манипуляции с кнопками, можно прямо в нем написать ваш код, или вызвать экшн кнопки в который передать индекс ячейки.

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`